# Which replacement water supply line shut off valve will work under my laundry room sink?

Tags: plumbing, repair

I noticed a leak under my laundry room sink today and was trying to fix the plumbing connection myself. I already turned off the house water main valve. I managed to pull the metal mesh tube (braided flexible water supply line) off the white plastic tubing base (shut off valve) and suspect it was the aging rubber seal that caused the leakage.

More recently I pulled off the plastic cap (shut off valve) on the tubing base (escutcheon) using a wrench. It was sitting on a metal stub that seems to have very little screw thread. What’s the recommended replacement adaptor (shut off valve) for such bare metal tubing stub? [image: bare metal tubing stub, very little thread]

Thanks a lot!

[image: underneath the sink, including metal mesh tubes and white tubing connector]
[image: laundry room sink base]

Comment: @jsotola I updated my question since I managed to pull off the adaptor and decided that connecting the tube to the base is a bad idea (as you see the plastic connector is broken)

Comment: I believe the white plastic "cap" is just a plastic shut off valve with a push-on style connection to the copper pipe coming out of the wall. Be sure you remove that toothed metal ring before installing a new shut off valve, and make sure the outside of the copper pipe is clean and smooth so the new shut off valve makes a reliable seal onto it. The plastic "base" is just a cosmetic plate called an "escutcheon".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the plastic cap from the base, by repeatedly turning the cap using a wrench. That exposed the copper tube stub coming out of the wall. I left the white base intact.

Then I went to home depot to buy a replacement metal mesh tube, as well as a push connect brasscraft 1/4 turn angle valve like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-1-2-in-Push-Connect-Inlet-x-3-8-in-Compression-Outlet-1-4-Turn-Angle-Valve-G2PS19X-C1/204163385?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&&mtc=Shopping-CM-F_D26P-G-D26P-026_001_PIPE_FITTING-MULTI-NA-NA-SMART-2998850-WF-PIPE_AND_FITTINGS_New_Engen_PL3&cm_mmc=Shopping-CM-F_D26P-G-D26P-026_001_PIPE_FITTING-MULTI-NA-NA-SMART-2998850-WF-PIPE_AND_FITTINGS_New_Engen_PL3-71700000081597013-58700006937676208-92700062365702238&gclid=CjwKCAjwx46TBhBhEiwArA_DjK_W_QKoIFUbmT9x4-uwpobH5o9WWGh1ma8Ps5FfHHzMXTPGwmh8iBoCgXQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

The push connect valve can be pushed into the tube stub. It will still be able to turn freely, but should keep the water supply sealed.

Here are a few relevant youtube links:

"Which Type of Water Supply Valve Should You Use: Compression or Push Fit?"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2yAHdqKgL8&feature=share

"How to Replace a FlowTite Push/Pull Valve with a Standard Shut Off Valve for a Dishwasher"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmceXF3MJOc&feature=share

"How to Install Water Shutoff Valves with Push-On Connectors"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVD-ZMC2jA0&feature=share